# how to make a opened buffer read only without reloading again with 'find-file-read-only'

Tags: emacs

I like to have my coding buffers read-only when I am not editing them (like Vi modes edit, read-only). For that, I can use `C-x C-q` for turning a emacs buffer on/off the writable status. Seems that this write-locking feature has some inheritance from RCS or similar way of file-loking/revision-system so working with files under Version Control does not work:

```
C-x C-q
File is under version-control; use C-x v v to check in/out
```

I don't want to check in/out I want only to prevent "cat-typing". I can write a macro flip-flop find-file-read-only '/'find-file ' and give some key-binding to it but I am sure there would be a solution inside emacs or .el written already. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `view-mode` instead.

Comment: thanks that is what I wanted. Also I have realised that C-x C-q works in emacs22 (my clusters where in emacs21 until recently). They give you the warning/suggestion to use `c-x v v` but it locks the file anyway. Now I only need to remap c-x c-q to view-mode.

Comment: The warning is just telling you that the behaviour changed. C-x C-q used to change its behaviour if the directory was under version control, but in Emacs 22 it was decided that leaving it with its normal behaviour was more useful, especially since modern vc systems do not require explicit checkout by default, so the association between being read-only and version control is no longer relevant.

Comment: Additionally, to open a file directly in view mode, one can do `M-x view-file`. `find-file-read-only` (`C-x C-r`) opens a file as read-only but not in view mode.

Answer (score 4):

or you can hook find-file

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook
  '(lambda ()
     (when (and (buffer-file-name)
        (file-exists-p (buffer-file-name))
        (file-writable-p (buffer-file-name)))
       (message "Toggle to read-only for existing file")
       (toggle-read-only 1))))
```

and using C-x C-q to change the read-only state of the file

Answer (score 2):

You can set a [file variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables), settting the value of **buffer-read-only** to a positive value.

You need to set it on the first 2 lines of a file. For example, here I set it to one into a python buffer:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 ; buffer-read-only: 1 ; -*-
```

Like that, you won't need to remember after each opening to set it manually.

Comment: But the file then becomes uneditable. If emacs didn't question the setting when you went to load it, you'd have to use some other editor to remove the variable setting before you'd be able to change it in emacs again.